# Cassandra - multiple counters based on timeframe

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am building an application and using Cassandra as my datastore.  In the app, I need to track event counts per user, per event source, and need to query the counts for different windows of time.  For example, some possible queries could be:

- Get all events for user A for the last week.
- Get all events for all users for yesterday where the event source is source S.
- Get all events for the last month.

Low latency reads are my biggest concern here. From my research, the best way I can think to implement this is a different counter tables for each each permutation of source, user, and predefined time.  For example, create a count_by_source_and_user table, where the partition key is a combination of source and user ID, and then create a count_by_user table for just the user counts.

This seems messy. What's the best way to do this, or could you point towards some good examples of modeling these types of problems in Cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. If latency is your main concern, and it should be if you have already chosen Cassandra, you need to create a table for each of your queries. This is the recommended way to use Cassandra: optimize for read and don't worry about redundant storage. And since within every table data is stored sequentially according to the index, then you cannot index a table in more than one way (as you would with a relational DB). I hope this helps. Look for the "Data Modeling" presentation that is usually given in "Cassandra Day" events. You may find it on "Planet Cassandra" or John Haddad's blog.